# Is this error complaining about missing build-tools ? (Paramiko)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, pip, arm

I'm installing Paramiko on arm architecture and during install I get this error:

[image]

I'm not 100% sure. Does this error mean that I need to install build-tools first ? It's complaining about gcc compiler so that's kinda hinting me that build-tools are needed before proceeding.

Any feedback much appreciated.

**Update:**

Installing `libffi-dev` revealed another missing dependency:

[image]

This time it's Pynacl and Cryptography that's missing.

Comment: Where possible, please share the text directly instead of a screenshot of text. You've not menioned what distribution you're using. This is also an error during `pip install`, which you've not mentioned at all in your question.

Comment: I'm so sorry for forgetting to include distro. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I edited tags as well.

Comment: No problem - it's helpful to have as much information as possible when trying to understand what went wrong... did you try installing the package mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this error mean that I need to install build-tools first?

No, `gcc` *is* present, and is probably producing this error message (can't quite see, it's off the top of your screenshot)... try just running `gcc` on the command line.

What's actually missing is `ffi.h` (see the error towards the top of the screen).

Try installing `libffi-dev` (Debian / Ubuntu) / `libffi-devel` (Redhat / Fedora), depending on your distribution.

Comment: It did the trick, yes ! However now it throws error and I don't like that it says it can't be installed directly. Sounds like I have to build it from source. Please see edit.

Comment: `opensslv.h` is what's actually missing and hence the packages fail to build.

Comment: Build of Cryptography fixed by installing `libssl-dev`.

Comment: Have you tried installing `libssl-dev` to resolve `opensslv.h`? (the header to package name is often trivially resolvable, via google, etc...)

Comment: Yes it worked for the Cryptography package. Now I'm dealing with failing Pynacl. Thank you for your assistance !